# Create list of unique URLs using R Studio

Tags: r, list, series

### I'm new to R Studio and biting off more than I can chew  :)

I'm trying to use R Studio create a list of URLs. The URLs all follow the same logic, only varying by location search string, year, and month. Below are a few examples:

> https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=mar%20del%20plata&year=2021&month=10#calendar

> https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=bendigo%20victoria&year=1969&month=7#calendar

> https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=2025&month=2#calendar

I've tried using `paste0()` and `c()`:

```
URLs <- paste0("https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=",c(1969:2031),"&month=",c(1:12),"#calendar")
```

However, by using two separate instances of `c()` for Year and Month, the sequences generated are independent of one another and I end up with 60 different URLs instead of 750. **Is there a way to generate a series of Months, `1:12`, for each year in a series of Years, `1969:2031`, using `paste0()`?** Is this even the best approach for what I'm trying to accomplish? And if so, is there also a way to generate this series of Years and Months for multiple locations as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `expand.grid` to create a dataframe and `apply` to collapse all rows into a single string.

```r
base_url <- 'https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&'

year_url <- paste0("year=",c(1969:2031))

mon_url <- paste0("&month=",c(1:12),"#calendar")

out_url <- apply(expand.grid(base_url, year_url, mon_url), 1, paste, collapse = '')

length(out_url)
#> [1] 756

head(out_url)
#> [1] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1969&month=1#calendar"
#> [2] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1970&month=1#calendar"
#> [3] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1971&month=1#calendar"
#> [4] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1972&month=1#calendar"
#> [5] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1973&month=1#calendar"
#> [6] "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=parkville%20missouri%20usa&year=1974&month=1#calendar"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Or a different option using `rep` to repeat the shorter vectors (`base_url` and `mon_url`) the same number of times in the longest vector (`year_url`)

```r
paste0(rep(base_url, each = length(year_url)), 
       year_url, 
       rep(mon_url, each = length(year_url)))
```